# Scala 2.13 : wrong number of type parameters for method map

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

I am newbie to scala and I migrate some code from scala 2.12 to 13.
I have the following code

```
override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    StructType(schema.fields ++ this.getOutputCols.map[StructField, Array[StructField]]( col => StructField(col, StringType)))
  }
```

I face the following error
error:

```
wrong number of type parameters for method map: [B](f: String => B)(implicit ct: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
[ERROR]     StructType(schema.fields ++ this.getOutputCols.map[StructField, Array[StructField]]( col => StructField(col, StringType)))
```

Can you explain why scala 2.13 has this problem, I dont find something related to the documentation
The map method tries to convert the array and it should be ok

Answer (score 5):

2.13 was a rewrite of the collections - see https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html.

In your case in particular the issue is exactly as error says:

- 2.12 took 2 type parameters in `.map`

  ```
  def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Array[A], B, That]): That
  ```
- 2.13 takes 1 type parameter in `.map`

  ```
  def map[B](f: A => B): Array[B]
  ```

so in 2.13 it should be

```
  StructType(schema.fields ++ getOutputCols.map[StructField](col => StructField(col, StringType)))
```

Answer (score 2):

For Scala 2.12, the `map` method added to `Array` (via an implicit conversion to `WrappedArray`) has two type parameters, the second of which is used to select a `CanBuildFrom` instance to constrain the resulting collection type.

Scala 2.13 rewrites the collection APIs (including the `Array` enrichments) to not use the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism, therefore the `map` method (now added via `ArraySeq`) now only takes a single type parameter, the element type of the resulting `ArraySeq`.  You therefore don't need the `Array[StructField]` type parameter (and almost certainly don't actually need the `StructField` type parameter either).

```scala
this.getOutputCols.map(col => StructField(col, StringType)).toArray
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. And if I want to keep source code that will compile with both scala 2.13 and previous. Is there a directive like c++ that can direct the compiler what code to use when I build the 2.13 and the 2.12 version?

Comment: Usually you need to add `scala-collection-compat` dependency and import `scala.collection.compat._` definitions and use them instead, but in your case the cause is putting these type parameters while they can be inferred.

Comment: You can also, at least if using sbt, have separate `scala-2.12` and `scala-2.13` source directories.  You can then minimize duplication by factoring out "map one array into a new one" from your non-version-specific code into a trait implemented in both version-specific forms.